# Suggest Feature in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, search-suggestion

I am trying to implement suggest feature - Suggest Usage | Elasticsearch .NET Client [8.4] | Elastic 1 for handling misspelled words in my search implementation.

My search query is executed across multiple indices but while trying to use the suggest functionality , i am running into failures due to unmappaed fields.

Suppose i have an index named People which has a field - "name". Another index named news which has a field named - "title". My query was executed across both indices at the same time and search query had rules defined for both name and title fields. But while using suggest, i only want to return suggestions for name field in person index as part of the same query. As a result of this my news index is returning a failure that no mapping found for field name.

Is there a work- around in the suggest functionality via which i can specify an index name for the field mentioned in suggest - Suggest Usage | Elasticsearch .NET Client [8.4] | Elastic 1 OR can i ignore unmapped fields and continue to return search results from the other index (news) without returning any suggestions for misspelled words for that index.

Comment: The above link doesn't work for me. Please check once again.

Comment: Here is the right link - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html